# attempting to upgrade pyarrow results in errors

Tags: python, upgrade, python-3.7, pyarrow

I ran this command to upgrade pyarrow from 2.0.0 to 3.0.0:

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade pyarrow
```

I got these errors:

```
Failed building wheel for pyarrow

...

-- Could NOT find Arrow (missing: Arrow_DIR)
-- Checking for module 'arrow'
--   No package 'arrow' found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Arrow (missing: ARROW_INCLUDE_DIR ARROW_LIB_DIR
  ARROW_FULL_SO_VERSION ARROW_SO_VERSION)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake_modules/FindArrow.cmake:419 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake_modules/FindArrowPython.cmake:46 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:214 (find_package)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Looks like it isn’t finding the prebuilt packages.  What version of Pip are you using?  Pyarrow 3.0 requires a newer version of pip (>= 19 I think)

Comment: pip3 -V shows "pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)". I'll try to update it and try updating pyarrow again.

Comment: I was able to run this to upgrade pip: "python3 -m pip install -U pip" and then my original command above and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pyarrow version 3.0 stopped shipping manylinux1 [source](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-11272) in favor of only shipping manylinux2010 and manylinux2014 wheels.

This means that starting with pyarrow 3.0 you will need pip >= 19.0 if you would like to avoid building from source.

Please also note that the default version of pip on Ubuntu 18 is pip version 9 and so you will need to upgrade pip (I've found most users with this issues seem to be coming from Ubuntu 18).